# The application sporadically hung forever

Tags: wpf, hittest, hung

I've bothered for a question for weeks.

The UI of my application  sometimes would run into **busy forever**, the cursor is circle round and round and the UI seems cannot accept any click event. and this is sporadic.

Today I'm lucky to get this happend in my test computer.I can see this process **always occupy the 25%** of CPU usage ,and my computer is quad-core. I use the "Windbg" and attached that process(before that i use "Process Explorer" and found the thread use most resource is 1a24 ).

then I use following command and corresponding output:

```
0:011> !threads
ThreadCount:      20
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 10
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       8
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                           PreEmptive                                                   Lock
       ID  OSID        ThreadOBJ     State GC       GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
   0    1  1840 0000000000604c20   2006020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 STA
   2    2   200 000000000060af60      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
XXXX    3       000000001d5cff50     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA
  11    4  1a24 000000001d5e1fe0      7020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 STA
XXXX    5       000000001d64a600   1019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    6       000000001d634c40   1019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    7       00000000244efa40   1019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    8       0000000024547280   1019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    9       0000000024503790   1019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  23    a  1754 00000000244c8c40   100a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  24    b   d44 00000000245b5020   1000220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  25    c  1368 0000000024618140   8009220 Enabled  0000000005f22278:0000000005f236a8 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  10    d  1604 0000000024615810       220 Enabled  0000000005f29338:0000000005f296a8 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn
  29    e  1b5c 00000000244ed820      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA
  30    f  1fb8 00000000246914e0      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA
  16   10   b70 0000000034246b00       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn
  28   11  20b8 000000003427bdd0   2000220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn
XXXX   12       0000000034361dc0  21019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   13       00000000343624d0  21019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005f89f0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  38   14  1a48 0000000034362be0   1009220 Enabled  0000000005f299d8:0000000005f2b6a8 00000000005f89f0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
0:011> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x1a24 (11)
Child SP         IP               Call Site
0000000020f55b10 000000005d221fc8 [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0000000020f55b10] System.Windows.Media.Composition.MilCoreApi.MilUtility_PolygonHitTest(System.Windows.Media.Composition.MilMatrix3x2D*, System.Windows.Media.Composition.MIL_PEN_DATA*, Double*, System.Windows.Point*, Byte*, UInt32, UInt32, Double, Boolean, System.Windows.Point*, Boolean ByRef)
0000000020f55a90 000007fee273aa54 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Windows.Media.Composition.MilMatrix3x2D*, System.Windows.Media.Composition.MIL_PEN_DATA*, Double*, System.Windows.Point*, Byte*, UInt32, UInt32, Double, Boolean, System.Windows.Point*, Boolean ByRef)
0000000020f55bc0 000007fee26f8459 System.Windows.Media.Geometry.ContainsInternal(System.Windows.Media.Pen, System.Windows.Point, Double, System.Windows.Media.ToleranceType, System.Windows.Point*, UInt32, Byte*, UInt32)
0000000020f55d00 000007fee2dbbc07 System.Windows.Media.LineGeometry.ContainsInternal(System.Windows.Media.Pen, System.Windows.Point, Double, System.Windows.Media.ToleranceType)
0000000020f55e50 000007fee309cd23 System.Windows.Media.HitTestWithPointDrawingContextWalker.DrawGeometry(System.Windows.Media.Brush, System.Windows.Media.Pen, System.Windows.Media.Geometry)
0000000020f55f00 000007fee2dce89d System.Windows.Media.HitTestDrawingContextWalker.DrawLine(System.Windows.Media.Pen, System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.Point)
0000000020f55f90 000007fee26d4907 System.Windows.Media.RenderData.DrawingContextWalk(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContextWalker)
0000000020f56390 000007fee26f86b0 System.Windows.Media.RenderData.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Point)
0000000020f563e0 000007fee2c29a6e System.Windows.Media.DrawingVisual.HitTestCore(System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f56460 000007fee26ab086 System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPointInternal(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f56490 000007fee26aae70 System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f568e0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f56d30 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f57180 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f575d0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f57a20 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f57e70 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f582c0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f58710 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f58b60 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f58fb0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f59400 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f59850 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f59ca0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5a0f0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5a540 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5a990 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5ade0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5b230 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5b680 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5bad0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5bf20 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5c370 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5c7c0 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5cc10 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5d060 000007fee26aad2c System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTestPoint(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters)
0000000020f5d4b0 000007fee26aa7c6 System.Windows.Media.Visual.HitTest(System.Windows.Media.HitTestFilterCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestResultCallback, System.Windows.Media.HitTestParameters)
0000000020f5d560 000007fee26a4d40 System.Windows.UIElement.InputHitTest(System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.IInputElement ByRef, System.Windows.IInputElement ByRef)
0000000020f5d640 000007fee26ddf11 System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.LocalHitTest(Boolean, System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.PresentationSource, System.Windows.IInputElement ByRef, System.Windows.IInputElement ByRef)
0000000020f5d720 000007fee26ddbdf System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.GlobalHitTest(Boolean, System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.PresentationSource, System.Windows.IInputElement ByRef, System.Windows.IInputElement ByRef)
0000000020f5d880 000007fee2ba87e0 System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.GlobalHitTest(Boolean, System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.PresentationSource)
0000000020f5d8e0 000007fee308d638 System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.PreNotifyInput(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.NotifyInputEventArgs)
0000000020f5db60 000007fee26ccc69 System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
0000000020f5dbf0 000007fee26dc66d System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.Synchronize()
0000000020f5dca0 000007fee26df32d System.Windows.Input.InputManager.HitTestInvalidatedAsyncCallback(System.Object)
0000000020f5dce0 000007fee478d11a System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
0000000020f5dd40 000007fee478d0a7 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
0000000020f5dda0 000007fee49ba6ad System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
0000000020f5de00 000007fee4791105 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
0000000020f5deb0 000007fef6103188 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
0000000020f5e5d8 000007fef70935b4 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 0000000020f5e5d8] System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
0000000020f5e700 000007fef60f17f1 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
0000000020f5e760 000007fef60f173b System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
0000000020f5e7b0 000007fee4790f3d System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
0000000020f5e820 000007fee478abff System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
0000000020f5e8d0 000007fee478af53 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
0000000020f5e990 000007fee478d440 MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
0000000020f5ea40 000007fee478d2b7 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
0000000020f5ea90 000007fee478d11a System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
0000000020f5eaf0 000007fee478d0a7 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
0000000020f5eb50 000007fee49ba6ad System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
0000000020f5ebb0 000007fee478a258 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
0000000020f5ec70 000007fee478c914 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
0000000020f5eda0 000007fee4936cc0 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
0000000020f5f0d8 000007fef7035757 [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0000000020f5f0d8] MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
0000000020f5f0a0 000007fee47b0ff0 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
0000000020f5f170 000007fee478943a System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
0000000020f5f250 000007ff0017d0d8 MyApplication.StartWindow()
0000000020f5f2e0 000007fef60f182c System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
0000000020f5f340 000007fef60f173b System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
0000000020f5f390 000007fef6186f9d System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
0000000020f5f7e8 000007fef70935b4 [GCFrame: 0000000020f5f7e8] 
0000000020f5fbd0 000007fef70935b4 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000020f5fbd0] 
0:011> ~11s
```

and I found that only found call stack is "0000000020f5f250 000007ff0017d0d8 MyApplication.StartWindow()".
and cannot follow the following call stack.

and anytime I found the current thread "CallStack" from "Process Explorer" is :

```
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+0x23b95
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+0x24ec7
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+0x242bc
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!WgxConnection_Create+0x2a39
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilCompositionEngine_DeinitializePartitionManager+0x398f
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilUtility_PolygonBounds+0x705
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilUtility_PolygonBounds+0x742
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilUtility_PolygonBounds+0x610
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilCompositionEngine_DeinitializePartitionManager+0x3aad
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilCompositionEngine_DeinitializePartitionManager+0x39c7
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!MilUtility_PathGeometryBounds+0x1993
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+0x235ea
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!WgxConnection_Create+0x204ee
clr.dll+0x17c7
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x33aa54
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2f8459
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x9bbc07
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0xc9cd23
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x9ce89d
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2d4907
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2f86b0
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x829a6e
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2ab086
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2aae70
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2aad2c
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2aa7c6
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2a4d40
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2ddf11
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2ddbdf
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x7a87e0
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0xc8d638
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2ccc69
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2dc66d
PresentationCore.ni.dll+0x2df32d
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11d11a
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11d0a7
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x34a6ad
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x121105
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x383188
clr.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x53f34
clr.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x54049
clr.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x540c5
clr.dll!CoUninitializeEE+0x32872
clr.dll!CoUninitializeEE+0x32691
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x3717f1
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x37173b
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x120f3d
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11abff
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11af53
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11d440
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11d2b7
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11d11a
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11d0a7
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x34a6ad
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11a258
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11c914
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x2c6cc0
clr.dll!CoUninitializeEE+0x31a67
USER32.dll!TranslateMessageEx+0x2a1
USER32.dll!TranslateMessage+0x1ea
clr.dll+0x17c7
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x140ff0
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0x11943a
```

Can anyone help to tell me how to find the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds kind of like that bitmap issue they keep chasing down.  Try disabling hardware rendering and see if that helps.